# Trouble with refactoring code for rspec feature tests in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I am trying to give the user of my web app the ability to login with a password.  I am rolling my own authentication instead of using a gem.  I read this article about refactoring Rspec/Capybara tests:

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/rspec-integration-tests-with-capybara

I liked what I read and decided to give refactoring a try.  I created a session helper file for my feature tests.

```
module Features
  module SessionHelpers
    def sign_in
      user = create(:user)
      visit '/authentications/new'
      fill_in 'Login', with: user.name
      fill_in 'Password', with:  user.password
     click_button 'Sign in'
   end
 end
end
```

I then called the sign_in function in my login tests.  Here is a little sample.

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature "signing in" do
  before :each do
    User.create(:name => 'user@example.com', :password => 'caplin')
  end

  scenario "user who logs in with correct credentials" do
    sign_in
    expect(page).to have_content 'Hi user@example.com'
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting this error message:

```
2) signing in user who logs in with correct credentials
     Failure/Error: sign_in
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `create' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_3:0x007ffc85012438>
     # ./spec/support/features/session_helpers.rb:4:in `sign_in'
     # ./spec/features/user_logs_in_spec.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Basically, I need some way to grab the user I created and pass it into the sign_in function.  Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing your first issue is a different test configuration than the one the ThoughBot example has. `create` is not to my knowledge a default method available in RSpec; I'm going to guess they've added every FactoryGirl method to the testing scope. If you're using FactoryGirl, you can get the same behavior by just namespacing the create command:

```
 def sign_in
   user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
   visit '/authentications/new'
   fill_in 'Login', with: user.name
   fill_in 'Password', with:  user.password
   click_button 'Sign in'
 end
```

However, this won't quite get you everything that you asked for, since you still won't be able to add a custom user. An easy way for this would allow for a user to be passed in:

```
def sign_in(user=nil)
  user ||= FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  ...
end
```

This will create the user for you if you don't pass one in on the `sign_in` call.

Going back to the spec you posted, you'd want to change it to this:

```
feature "signing in" do
  before :each do
    @user = User.create(:name => 'user@example.com', :password => 'caplin')
  end

  scenario "user who logs in with correct credentials" do
    sign_in(@user)
    expect(page).to have_content 'Hi user@example.com'
  end
end
```

You'd need to attach the user you created to a variable (`@user`), then pass it to the `sign_in` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in you model

```
module Features
  module SessionHelpers
    def sign_in
      user = create(:user) # <- this method allow only in FactoryGirl
      visit '/authentications/new'
      fill_in 'Login', with: user.name
      fill_in 'Password', with:  user.password
     click_button 'Sign in'
   end
 end
end
```

i use another way. Create a class and include `FactroyGirl` methods and `Capybara::DSL` like this

```
class Features
  include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  include Capybara::DSL

  def sign_in
    user = create(:user)                     #<- FactroyGirl
    visit '/authentications/new'             #<- Capybara
    fill_in 'Login', with: user.name         #<- Capybara
    fill_in 'Password', with:  user.password #<- Capybara
    click_button 'Sign in'                   #<- Capybara
    self                                     #<- return page
  end
end
```

in spec

```
feature "signing in" do
  let(:login_user) { Features.new }

  scenario "user who logs in with correct credentials" do
    page = login_user.sign_in
    expect(page).to have_content 'Hi user@example.com'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by including FactoryGirl in your tests. Your RSpec configuration block (in spec_helper.rb or in the new version of RSpec rails_helper.rb) should look like this:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```